# Can't create Deep Learning VM using Tensorflow 2.0 framework

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to create a Deep Learning Virtual Machine using Google Cloud Platform that uses tensorflow 2.0. But when I instantiate it i get the following error:

`deep-learning-training-vm: {"ResourceType":"compute.v1.instance","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":400,"errors":[{"domain":"global","message":"Invalid value for field 'resource.disks[0].initializeParams.sourceImage': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/click-to-deploy-images/global/images/tf-2-0-cu100-experimental-20190909'. The referenced image resource cannot be found.","reason":"invalid"}],"message":"Invalid value for field 'resource.disks[0].initializeParams.sourceImage': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/click-to-deploy-images/global/images/tf-2-0-cu100-experimental-20190909'. The referenced image resource cannot be found.","statusMessage":"Bad Request","requestPath":"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project/zones/us-west1-b/instances","httpMethod":"POST"}}`

I don't quite understand the error but I believe that gcp is not able to find the right image for my virtual machine, i.e, the image that have this version of tensorflow in it (maybe because of TF 2.0 release?).

Have someone faced this problem before? Is there a way to create a DL VM using tensorflow 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to be a transient issue, since it is available now.

In addition, you can create your DL VM via gcloud. Here's an example of the command:

```
gcloud compute instances create INSTANCE_NAME \
  --zone=ZONE \
  --image-family=tf2-latest-cu100 \
  --image-project=deeplearning-platform-release \
  --maintenance-policy=TERMINATE \
  --accelerator="type=nvidia-tesla-v100,count=1" \
  --metadata="install-nvidia-driver=True,proxy-mode=project_editors" \
  --machine-type=n2-highmem-8
```

There's more information on how to this in the [DL documentation](https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/docs/tensorflow_start_instance#creating_a_tensorflow_instance_from_the_command_line).

Also, if you are looking to create a VM with Tensorflow and Jupyter, you can try using [AI Platform Notebooks](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/overview).

When you [create a new Notebook](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/create-new#top_of_page), you can select Tensorflow 2.0  and further customize it to select the accelerator, machine-type, etc.